# Multivariate K-Means Plotting

Tags: r, plot, k-means

I'm currently working on a K-Means cluster project with N-dimensions. The issue I'm running into right now is trying to depict my results with K-Mean on a graph.

Most examples I've seen either plot K-Means with 2 variables or tabulate the results. Is there no way to represents the results in 2-dimensions?

I've taken a look at plotCluster, but it seems it graphs based off of the first two columns in the dataFrame.

**Minimum Verifiable Example**

I suppose any dataframe with > 2 columns of data satisfies this particular question.

Comment: An option is to plot the first two principal components and color by cluster. This is a very open-ended question.

Comment: The function `clusplot` in the cluster package will do what @bouncyball suggested (plot first two principal components).   You could also look at tSNE which is another popular way to map your data down to two dimensions for graphing.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know clusplot plots by first 2 principal components. I wasn't really familiar with this terminology until recently as I was exploring how to graph KMeans. I stumbled across PCA and was unsure of what to make of all of this. On top of functions like plotCluster, I got pretty confused how all these functions were graphing the data.